# How to reflect 3 relationships in a Chord Diagram and avoid label overlap?

Tags: r, matrix, chord-diagram, circlize

I am trying to great a chord diagram that reflects a 3 way connection that goes from the individual sample to species to what label it falls under. However when I try to create my chord diagram some of my labels are overlapping and you cant see what is each part. This doesn't happen when I use a smaller sample amount like 20, but I have a large data set of 40 which leads to overlap. Also my third label "seafood" does not show up at all and just disappears when I want to show that all those species fall under same label

The example data I have is:

```
Sample  Species  Label
L1  Shark   Seafood
L2  Tuna    Seafood
L3  Shark   Seafood
L4  Shrimp  Seafood
L5  Crab    Seafood
L6  Tuna    Seafood
L7  Shrimp  Seafood
L8  Shark   Seafood
L9  Shark   Seafood
L10 Crab    Seafood
L11 Tuna    Seafood
L12 Shrimp  Seafood
L13 Crab    Seafood
L14 Crab    Seafood
L15 Shark   Seafood
L16 Tuna    Seafood
L17 Tuna    Seafood
L18 Shark   Seafood
L19 Shark   Seafood
L20 Shrimp  Seafood
L21 Shark   Seafood
L22 Tuna    Seafood
L23 Shark   Seafood
L24 Shrimp  Seafood
L25 Crab    Seafood
L26 Tuna    Seafood
L27 Shrimp  Seafood
L28 Shark   Seafood
L29 Shark   Seafood
L30 Crab    Seafood
L31 Tuna    Seafood
L32 Shrimp  Seafood
L33 Crab    Seafood
L34 Crab    Seafood
L35 Shark   Seafood
L36 Tuna    Seafood
L37 Tuna    Seafood
L38 Shark   Seafood
L39 Shark   Seafood
L40 Shrimp  Seafood
```

The code I have is:
library(circlize)

col.pal = c(Sample.= "blue", Species = "red", Label = "green")

chordDiagram(Example, grid.col = col.pal)

The plot I get is:
[image]

What I would like to get is this where there is a third spot where all the lines from species would then connect to the seafood and all labels are visible:
[image]

Please let me know any tips! I am totally new to chord diagrams and pretty new to coding so im sure im missing something. I saw some people use matrices for their chord diagrams but when I tried to do this i received error: "error non-numeric argument to mathematical function".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure a chord diagram is right for this sort of relationship, even if it is pretty. Essentially it sounds like you want a hierarchical graph (i.e. a tree structure). You can still get this to be attractive, colorful and even circular. Here's an example using your data and the `tidygraph` and `ggraph` packages:

```r
library(tidygraph)
library(ggraph)
library(extrafont)

df1 <- Example[2:1]
df1$Sample <- paste(df1$Species, df1$Sample)
df2 <- Example[3:2]
names(df2) <- names(df1)

as_tbl_graph(rbind(df1, df2)) %>%
  activate(nodes)%>%
  mutate(group = ifelse(grepl(' ', name), sub(' .*$', '', name), name),
         name = ifelse(grepl(' ', name), sub('^.* ', '', name), name)) %>%
  ggraph(layout = 'igraph', algorithm = 'tree', circular = TRUE) +
  geom_edge_arc(aes(color = factor(from)), width = 2, alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_node_circle(aes(r = nchar(name)/45, fill = group), color = NA) +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name), family = "Roboto Condensed", fontface = 2,
                 size = 6, color = "gray30") +
  theme_graph() +
  coord_equal() +
  scale_edge_color_brewer(palette = 'Pastel2') +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Pastel2', 
                    limits = c('Shark', 'Tuna', 'Shrimp', 'Crab', 'Seafood')) +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

[image]

Comment: Oo okay i definitely think this would work! Quick question though, when I run your code I can get the shape of the graph but its very faded and doesn't have the labels on it and i get warning: 'There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)'. Any idea what im missing? I did run warnings() and the warning is: "In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  no font could be found for family "Roboto Condensed". I added the ggraph, tidygraph, and extrafont packages so I am not sure whats wrong...

Comment: @IzOss you may not have that particular font on your system. Just remove the bit that says `family = "Roboto Condensed"`- the default font should still look good.

Comment: that worked in getting my labels and clearing the warning. But I still have a lot of overlap like the chord diagram I was trying to do before. My real data set has about 125 variables, do you think thats too many to create this type of graph or is there a way I can fit them all in?

Comment: @lzOss I think 125 is definitely pushing it if you want all the points to be labelled _and_ on a circle (unless you make your plot very large). If you make your plot full screen they _might_ all fit in. Another option may be to miss out or shorten the labels on the actual samples (like removing the `L` before the number). Since the problem is related to the number of points you are trying to plot, it might be best to post your real data (or something the same size as your real data), since the samples you posted don't replicate the problem you are encountering.

Comment: Okay gotcha, I tried getting rid of the 'L' like you said and that definitely helped a little, but I will try to do a new post with an accurate depiction of my data so that maybe that will help. Thank you for all your help!